# What are my options for inserting a back page into my document?

Tags: titles, lastpage

I'm developing a template for articles and so far I've got the `title_page.tex` and `main_document.tex` all sorted out and I'm happy with that.

My problem is I also need to have a back page in the document. I'm finding this quite difficult.

For my title_page, I used the `\begin{titlepage}` group and then inserted it into the main document with `\input{title_page.tex}`. I've tried to make a similar `.tex` file for my back page, utilising the `\begin{titlepage}` environment.

I want my back page to go after my bibliography. When I insert this, the pagenumbering (I'm using `lastpage` package) messes up. Is there any way I can seemlessly bolt on a final page to my tex document?

[EDIT]

Thank you for the comments. I have stopped using the titlepage environment. To solve the issue with the page numbering, I just put:

```
 \addtocounter{page}{-1}
```

on the back page file. I think that's all I wanted.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean a final even page, with a blank odd one if necessary?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `titlepage` environment resets the page number, that's true, at least for `book` and `article` classes. In my opinion, you don't need such `titlepage` modifications for a back page

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies! When I say "final page", I mean, a fancy looking graphical page which marks the end of the document. It's essentially a title page, but is the final page in the document. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you tried just using `\clearpage`? If so, what made that a wrong choice?

Comment: I have used \clearpage -> \pagestyle{empty} and then specified the page. I think what I basically need to do is make "lastpage" stop incrementing beyond the bibliography. Then everything would work fine.

Comment: Manual changes to the page counters are error-prone. The page counter is an unreliable friend, actually!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, the last page must be an even-numbered one, even if it is not numbered.

You have to clear the content pages first, and check if the new page is an odd-numbered one. If this is the case, put dummy content on it, i.e. a `\null` and clear again with `\clearpage.

In order to forbid `lastpage` to go beyond the last real page (i.e. not the back page, I have chosen to use `\SuspendCounters` from `xassoccnt`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\finalpage}[1]{%
  \clearpage% Clear first
  \SuspendCounters{page}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \ifodd\c@page % Now, is it odd? 
  \null% 'fill` and clear again
  \clearpage
  \fi
  #1% Plase the content
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
There are \pageref{LastPage} pages in here!


\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\cite{Lam94}

\printbibliography


\blindtext[100]
\finalpage{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{ente}
  \end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `ente.jpg` image.

[image]

Comment: You can also use \cleardoublepage

Comment: @Philipp: That would leave the back page at an odd-numbered page

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the my page numbers being odd or even is the issue. I think I just need "lastpage" to stop increasing beyond the bibliography.

Comment: @user1147964: Yes, I will attack that as next problem ;-)

Comment: @user1147964: See the update, please

Comment: Thank you Christian. That's a much more succinct way of doing it!

Comment: @user1147964: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!